# Does DreamWeaver force directory structure on a project, or is it configurable?

Tags: dreamweaver

I have an existing web app that has a very specific project directory structure.

I need to do some extensive frontend redesign and am considering using Adobe DW. I need DW to be able to load/open my existing project (root) folder and *not* force a specific directory structure on me.

Is this possible, or does DW force directory structure on you?

Comment: Yes it's possibe but I'd avoid dream weaver in general. It gets in the way more than helps in my experience.

Comment: The only feature of Dreamweaver I like is the ability to upload an arbitrary set of files from a random set of nested folders all at once. I don't know a single other ftp file uploader that can do this. Beyond that, I don't use any of DW features.

Comment: @Yorik ever heard of [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) or its derivatives like unison. And how about `scp` with the `-r` [flag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304895/how-to-scp-a-folder-from-remote-to-local) or by passing list of [filenames](http://superuser.com/questions/115997/how-can-i-copy-multiple-files-over-scp-in-one-command)

Comment: I have tried a few of those and I am well-versed enough in scripting etc to get the list(s), but it is still an extra step I wish I could avoid. A lot of times I work on a small subset of files when working up a new feature or fixing something (js/foo.js; template/bar.php; images/icon_a.png) and if you can just highlight them in the tree and "put" all at once, this works great, and is a lot quicker than a "touch and a checksum" on the whole tree. I usually work iteratively so I tend to put and try a lot (on a local dev server of course). Lots of workarounds, but the feature itself is killer.

Comment: I was using source control for a little bit too, but it was kind of "heavy" for my purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost positive it won't force it's own structure on you. All you have to do is open a new project and tell it where the root folder is located and it's build based off that you already have. I'm not 100% sure so perhaps there is more of a power user out there with better advice. All I know is DW is super powerful.

Comment: This mirrors my experience as well